# Azure Blob Storage Python API performance

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Download ~60MB with python api can take more than 10-15 minutes oven more.
Is there a way/example to imporove the performance?

Comment: Just curious what you're expecting, as an answer. You've shown no code (whether raw API calls or using the python SDK). You've shared nothing about where you're running your download script from: A VM in the same region as your storage account? Different region? On-premises machine? Please edit your question accordingly, as there's currently no way to answer, other than to just throw out guesses. And, honestly, it's pretty much unheard of to take such a long time for a blob to download.

Comment: Try turning it off and on again.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your help!
I found that the container was cold blob storage.
Afer upgrade it to the hot container, the performance increase dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to a lot of factor such as slow internet speed, different Geo Location.

If client downloads a file through your Python API, you can definitely improve the overall performance by just passing [valet token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/valet-key) to client.

Then let the client downloads straight from Azure Blob Storage.

[image]

Comment: Not sure how you can propose a valet token (SAS) when the OP hasn't even given a single shred of detail about the problem itself. And at 15-20 minutes for a 60MB file, you're talking a download rate of a 56k modem. There's either a horrible network connection or a completely incorrect API implementation. But without any details, I don't see how a solution can be pitched.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description to compute your actual network bandwidth, it seems to be less than 1Mbps, which 544~816Kbps or 68.3~102.4KB/s for costing 10~15 min to download. Based on this bandwidth if it's truth, I think your case is normal.

Per my experience, for downloading a large blob, if the blob includes multi-blocks，a way to improve the download performance is first to [Get Block List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/get-block-list) of the blob, then to download them concurrently via [`Get Blob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/get-blob) with multithread or multiprocess in Python to write a file with [`file.seek(offset)`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) method which `offset` parameter is the size value of block ordered by block id. However, your blob size is just ~60MB which less than 64MB, normally it's a single block. So I think the way is not suitable for this case, besides to improve network bandwidth.